# How to reference ID property in relationship with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, parent-child, foreign-key-relationship

How do I map relationship, where child endpoint is exposed via Id property and not via whole Parent object?

Here is the example:

```
class Parent {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Chlidren { get; set; }
}

class Child {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the equivalent mappings I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Blabla"
                   namespace="Blabla"
                   auto-import="false">

    <typedef name="ChildrenList" class="Blabla" />

    <class name="Parent" table="Parent" lazy="false">
        <id name="Id" column="ID" type="Guid">
            <generator class="guid" />
        </id>

        <bag name="Children" table="Child"
                             cascade="save-update"
                             collection-type="ChildrenList"
                             lazy="false">
            <key column="ParentID" not-null="true" />
            <one-to-many class="Child" />
        </bag>
    </class>

    <class name="Child" table="Child" lazy="false">
        <id name="Id" column="ID" type="Guid">
            <generator class="guid" />
        </id>

        <!-- How to map ParentID here? -->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I create a parent, add some children to `Children` collection and then save the parent, everything is fine. But if save a parent object first, then create a child, setting its ParentID property to ID of the parent, then I get

```
NHibernate.PropertyValueException:
not-null property references a null or transient value Child._Parent.ChildrenBackref
```

All attempts to map `many-to-one` relationship resulted in different exceptions while creating NHibernate configuration. Mostly about object type mismatch.

I'm sure NHibernate is capable to handle this scenario. There must something fairly basic that I miss.

**EDIT:**

I think it make sense to the example test, which fails with above exception:

```
var child = new Child(Create.Saved<Parent>().Id); // this sets the ParentId property
this.Repository.Save(child); // here I get the exception
```

My thoughts why NHibernate is raising this: `Children` property of `Parent` class mapped in a way that says that a child cannot exist without a parent (`<key column="ParentID" not-null="true" />`). When I try to persist a child, NHibernate tries to resolve this relationship (to find a parent this child relates to) and fails, since being given no child endpoint (which otherwise would be `ParentId` property) in the mapping, it check for its own `Child._Parent.ChildrenBackref` endpoint, whatever it is.

This looks like a desired solution: Mapping `ParentId` property as child endpoint of the relationship. This would force NHibernate to resolve a parent by using value of `ParentId` property as parent's primary key.

The thing is I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

The one-to-many / many-to-one relationships you have in NHibernate always needs to have a dominant side (i.e. the side that manages the "saving").

```
<bag name="Children" table="Child"
                     cascade="save-update"
                     collection-type="ChildrenList"
                     lazy="false">
    <key column="ParentID" not-null="true" />
    <one-to-many class="Child" />
</bag>
```

The above is a one-to-many relationship where the dominant side is the parent. That means, you save the parent ... and that will save the parent first, then, the children (with the ParentId being null), then a subsequent update will be issued to set the child.ParentId.

Note:

**The child is inserted first with ParentId=null ... if you have a db or mapping restriction to say ParentId cannot be null, this action will fail.**

```
<bag name="Children" table="Child"
                     cascade="save-update"
                     collection-type="ChildrenList"
                     lazy="false"
                     inverse=true>
    <key column="ParentID" not-null="true" />
    <one-to-many class="Child" />
</bag>
```

Note the **inverse=true** attribute. This means the child object is dominant in the relationship, meaning the child object is in charge. The parent will be inserted, then the Id will be assiged to the child.ParentId, and then the child will be inserted **with the ParentId already set**.

In many cases, of course, you want to go either way. The easiest way to do this is to manage the relationship on both ends (unfortunately, you have to do this yourself).

On the Parent, you have a method:

```
public void AddChild(Child child)
{
   Children.Add(child);
   child.ParentId = Id;
}

public void RemoveChild(Child child)
{
    Children.Remove(child);
    child.ParentId = null;
}
```

On the Child, you have a method:

```
public void SetParent(Parent parent)
{
    ParentId = parent.Id;
    parent.Children.Add(this);
}
```

Using these methods to Add/Remove/Set, both sides are consistent after the action is performed. It, then, wouldn't matter whether you set **inverse=true** on the bag or not.

see http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-example

Comment: Your note about the insert with parentId as null is wrong since NHibernate 3.2.0. If you specify `not-null="true"` on the `<key>` NHibernate will insert the child with the parentId already set.

Comment: True about the comment **cremor** made. I do have restrictions in the database specifying the ParentID must not be null. And I do know what effect `inverse` attribute has. What I do not understand is why NHibernate throws `PropertyValueException` (see above) if (a) I'm saving child object, where no relationship with the parent specified (b) parent **is** persisted